# Issue in firebase facebook authentication after suceesful login from facebook in android

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

I am facing issue for fireback authentication. The facebook login is working fine for each facebook user. After facebook login we are using facebook token for Firebase facebook authentication. i have tried to login with developer account or testing account created at facebook developer account then we are able to login in firebase FB authencation also. But for other fb account the firebase authentication is not working (fb login working fine for all fb accounts).there is issue only after the fb login. For other fb accouts ( except developer account and testing account created in developer app) after successsfully fb login when code is trying to authenticating firebace then i am not receving any error message in logs and in try catch exception. Please help me to resolve this issue.

```
private void fbLoginRequest(CallbackManager callbackManager) {
    loginmanager = LoginManager.getInstance();
    AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
    if (accessToken != null) {
        loginmanager.logOut();
    }

    loginmanager.logInWithReadPermissions(activity,Arrays.asList("public_profile","email"));
    loginmanager.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(final LoginResult loginResult) {
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(),new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object,GraphResponse response) {

                    UserNormal userDetail = new UserNormal();
                    try {
                        email = object.getString("email");
                        id = object.getString("id");
                        name = object.getString("name");
                        first_name = object.getString("first_name");
                        last_name = object.getString("last_name");
                        JSONObject picture = object.getJSONObject("picture");
                        final JSONObject data = picture.getJSONObject("data");
                        profile_img_url = data.getString("url");
                    }
                    catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                    userDetail.setFirstName(first_name);
                    userDetail.setLastName(last_name);
                    userDetail.setCustomer_email(email);
                    userDetail.setCustomer_name(name);
                    userDetail.setCustomer_photo(profile_img_url);

            logInWithFbOnFireBase(loginResult.getAccessToken(),userDetail);
                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields","id,name,email,first_name,last_name,picture.width(300).height(300)");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            alertDialog.dismiss();
            HomeActivity.getInstance().viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
        }
    });

}


public void logInWithFbOnFireBase(AccessToken token,final UserNormal userDetail) {


    WebServices.getInstance().handleFbAccessTocken(activity,token,new FbAccessTokenHandler() {
        @Override
        public void OnSuccess(Task<AuthResult> task) {


        }

        @Override
        public void OnFail(String message) {
            view.showFeedbackMessage(message);
        }
    });
}
    public void handleFbAccessTocken(Activity activity,AccessToken token, final FbAccessTokenHandler handler) {
    AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
    BorideApplication.mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(activity, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        handler.OnSuccess(task);
                    }
                    else {
                        handler.OnFail(task.getException().getMessage());
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: i am facing issue on "handleFbAccessTocken" method. it is not authentication the firebace for fb logged in users except the developer account user.